# How to get the date time string from the object by calling getDate() in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I am calling the getDate() function in a joomla component model, and i am trying to retrieve the current date time and and it to database.

My code is like this:

```
$date = & JFactory::getDate();
$row->create_on= $date->toFormat();
```

first, do i need to use '&' in calling this function in the model

Second, this code pops up an error message saying i am calling an undefined method, toFormat().

I do not know what is wrong.
Hope some one can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: _“ am trying to retrieve the current date time and [insert?] it to database”_ – for that you don’t need to get the time in PHP, you can simply use [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) in your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use (Joomla core extensions use this for cDate and mDate storing in database):

```
$date = JFactory::getDate();
$row->create_on = $date->toSql(true);
```

And when using **&** symbol, it's recommended to use references only on variables, not methods or functions. In debug mode you would get notification about that.

**toSql** method has parameter to use local time (when true), or GMT time (when false), default value is false, so if you want to store local time, you need to pass **true** parameter.

Comment: thank you, it works. however the time is not in correct time zone.. i am in east zone 8, which is 8 hours later than the time that retrieved.

Comment: how to use the timezone offset?

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please check if it works for you.

Comment: hi, i changed, but there is no different.

Comment: Check you joomla settings in back-end -> System -> Global configuration -> Server -> Server Time Zone

Comment: You can always use $row->create_on = date('Y-m-d H:i:s); instead of using Joomla date.

Comment: Check your server configuration, maybe it's time zone set to GMT?

Comment: To use offset. Please set  the server configuration correctly first.
$config = JFactory::getConfig();  
$offset = $config->get('offset');
$date   = JFactory::getDate('',$offset);
Then pass the date to the object
$row->create_on = $date->toSql(true);